# React, nothing is shown after looping through an array of data with map method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Just started leaning Reac. Trying to build a simple App, which shows the list of Tasks. However when I run the App, it does not show anyout in the browser. There is no error in the console or anything. Not sure what is missing here.

Here is the code:

1. App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import TaskList from './TaskList';

function App() {

  const tasks = [
    {id:0,description:"1st Task",isDone:false},
    {id:1,description:"2st Task",isDone:false}
  ]

  return (
    <div>      
     <TaskList tasks={tasks} />
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

2. TaskList.js

```
import React from "react";
import Task from "./Task";

export default({ tasks }) => {
    return (
        <ul className="list-group">
        { 
        tasks.map(task => {            
            <li key={task.id} className="List-group-item">
                <Task task={task} />
            </li>
        })}
      </ul>
    )
}
```

3. Task.js

```
import React from "react";
export default ({task}) => {
    return(  
        <p>
         {task.description}
        </p>     
    )
}
```

The list of tasks are not shown in the screen, neither there is any error in console.

Answer (score 1):

Here is where you are doing wrong, in your `map` function in `TaskList.js` you are not returning anything. Try with this :

```js
import React from "react";
import Task from "./Task";

export default({ tasks }) => {
    return (
        <ul className="list-group">
        { 
        tasks.map(task => {
        
            return (<li key={task.id} className="List-group-item">
                      <Task task={task} />
                   </li>)
        })}
      </ul>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your TaskList component you didn't return anything you need to replace { by (

```js
import React from "react";
import Task from "./Task";

export default ({ tasks }) => {
  return (
    <ul className="list-group">
      {tasks.map((task) => (
        <li key={task.id} className="List-group-item">
          <Task task={task} />
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning anything in your `.map()` loop. It Should be

```
 tasks.map(task => {            
          return  <li key={task.id} className="List-group-item">
                <Task task={task} />
            </li>
        })}
```

Or since you don't have any other logic inside your callback function you can just remove the brackets and the arrow function will return the single jsx statement by default.

```
{tasks.map((task) => 
        <li key={task.id} className="List-group-item">
          <Task task={task} />
        </li>
      )}
```

Comment: thank you...It worked...but still not clear why the curly braces did not work. what is the difference?

Comment: as far I know, arrow functions need to have a curly braces

Comment: @user3161840 after arrow function is your return : if you have a logic you make a curly braces and when returning html you need to add return (your html here)   // if your arrow function desn't have any logic you can directly make your html after the =>

Comment: @user3161840 you can find some concrete examples [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing return from TaskList.js. Here in this line

```
tasks.map(task => {            
            <li key={task.id} className="List-group-item">
                <Task task={task} />
            </li>
        }
```

when using `{}` with arrow function you need to explicitly `return`.

```js
import React from 'react';
import Task from './Task';

export default function TaskList({ tasks }) {
  console.log(tasks);
  return (
    <ul className="list-group">
      {tasks.map((task) => ( // changed here. Note the braces
        <li key={task.id} className="List-group-item">
          <Task task={task} />
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}



import React from 'react';
export default function Task({ task }) {
  return <p>{task.description}</p>;
}




import React from "react";
import "./style.css";
import TaskList from "./TaskList"

export default function App() {
  const tasks = [
    {id:0,description:"1st Task",isDone:false},
    {id:1,description:"2st Task",isDone:false}
  ]

  return (
    <div>      
     <TaskList tasks={tasks} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```